# Laravel eloquent count by multiply columns

Tags: laravel, count, eloquent, multiple-columns

My table structure is as below

```
user_offer  user_accept    status
   4           3          canceled
   2           4          approved
   3           2          canceled
   1           2          approved
   2           1          approved
```

I need count of records with status approved for each user.
The result of request must be counts of records with status approved foreach unique user id that is in `user_offer` or `user_accept` table. For my example:

```
    user count
     2     3
     1     2
     4     1
```

Comment: can you explain where does `user (2) and count (3)` comes from? is it a user_id or number of users? What is count counting on?

Comment: your description its misleading actually !

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I understood you correctly, maybe could edit your question and give more detail.

If you want to count all users who have an excepted status 
you could do it in 2 ways.
First the model based way.

In this example I used the User model you may need to change to to your proper model, the model is linked to your database table so you could do something like this:

```
User::where('status', 'accepted')->count();
```

And second through the DB facade:

```
DB::table('users')->where('status', 'accepted')->count();
```

Comment: don't forget you are counting same users, you are basically counting how many rows are in db with user with status accepted!